# Martingales and optional stopping in biased games

Tags: martingales

As a martingale is a model of a fair game, and using optional stopping theorem assumes that you are dealing with a martingale, is it even possible to use optional stopping to find stopping time in an unfair situation? And how? (In conncetion to the Gambler's Ruin, finding probability of winning and loosing)

Comment: Are you familiar with super- and sub-martingales?

Comment: Somewhat, but i don't completly see how one can use them.